# InfluxDB checks with dynamic thresholds

Tags: influxdb

Looking at the examples for creating checks in InfluxDB I can only find examples for checks that have fixed thresholds. This example check query is made using the UI-interface:

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/monitor"
import "influxdata/influxdb/v1"

data = from(bucket: "FirstBucket")
    |> range(start: -5s)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "PLC1/Reg400003" or r["_measurement"] == "PLC1/Reg400001" or r["_measurement"] == "PLC1/Reg400002")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 5s, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)

option task = {name: "MyFirstCheck", every: 5s, offset: 0s}

check = {_check_id: "09b2b2f731634000", _check_name: "MyFirstCheck", _type: "threshold", tags: {myFirstCheckTag: "myFirstCheckTagValue"}}
info = (r) => r["value"] > 0.5    //Fixed threshold
crit = (r) => r["value"] > 35.0   //Fixed threshold
warn = (r) => r["value"] > 3.0    //Fixed threshold
messageFn = (r) => "Check: ${ r._check_name } is: ${ r._level }"

data |> v1["fieldsAsCols"]() |> monitor["check"](
    data: check,
    messageFn: messageFn,
    info: info,
    crit: crit,
    warn: warn,
)
```

What would be the best way to change that to thresholds that are, for instance, read from  an external source? Maybe I can replace the fixed thresholds with tag-values?

Comment: It looks like I'm going to need to perform a join with an SQL table to get the desired effect. Surely there must be an easier way??

Answer (score 0):

So I did some digging and came up with this solution:

```
import "csv"
csvData =
    "
_measurement,Max,Min
PLC1/Reg400001,15.43,1
PLC1/Reg400002,16.43,2
PLC1/Reg400003,17.43,3
PLC1/Reg400004,18.43,4
"

thresholds=csv.from(csv: csvData, mode: "raw")

tData=from(bucket: "FirstBucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "PLC1/Reg400001" or r["_measurement"] == "PLC1/Reg400002" or r["_measurement"] == "PLC1/Reg400003")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")

join(tables: {t1: thresholds, t2: tData}, on: ["_measurement"], method: "inner")
```

The join function adds the Max and min columns to the query result. These columns can be used as externally provided thresholds for generating checks (the CSV can be read from a URL later). This solution has no need for an SQL server.